# Checklists for instruction - direct or second person?

Tags: direct-objects

For instruction within a professional org, we utilize checklists for the specific parties to self-assess their "products". Because there is some unfamiliarity with the subject matter, we initially approached the checklists using second person to feel more approachable.

Example: `During keyboard testing, can you clearly see where the focus is on the page at all times?`

However, I think it may be better to be more direct, removing second person as checklists are instructional and direct.

Example: `During keyboard testing, is focus visible at all times?`

Is there a rule of thumb that applies here?

Comment: Whichever suits the style of the piece.

Comment: While both examples are in second person, "can you clearly see where" is extra wording you do not need in a written procedure. This is what I do for a living. On a call or in email, you might *make nice* with a novice who needs TLC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which is preferred really depends on the culture at your organization. However, saying it concisely using the imperative mood is both more efficient to write and has a stronger impact (e.g. your second example). It's a checklist -- people do not expect niceties, but quick help to get something done.